# Why does a bigger sample size give a more accurate result?

Tags: statistics

I am currently learning very basic statistics on my own.

I came across a question to prove that the sample mean is an unbiased estimator of the population mean.
If it is an unbiased estimator, **how come a larger sample size gives us a more reliable and accurate estimate?**

Sorry in advance for asking such a simple question!

Comment: There is no relation between being unbiased and being accurate. Why do you think so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you draw a random sample, it has some probability of being far from the mean. When you draw many samples, the probability that they are all simultaneously far from the mean is much lower. For this reason, the spread of the values decreases. More quantitatively, the variance gets divided by the number of samples. This variance reduction makes the estimation "more accurate".

Anyway variance reduction is not all, because the estimator could converge to a different value than what you want to estimate: accurate but… wrong. This is why you also want the estimator to be unbiased.